# Coefficient of restitution in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, collision

It seems that all books about special relativity only include discussion about perfectly elastic and perfectly inelastic collisions. The notion of the coefficient of restitution, $e$ in classical physics doesn't seem to appear in relativistic collisions.

My question is: **how do we formulate newton's experimental law in special relativity?** To be more specific, let particles $1,2$ collide to form particles $3,4$. Then (Let $P$ denote 4-momentum,$m$ denote rest mass)
$$
{P_{1}}_r+{P_{2}}_r={P_{3}}_r+{P_{4}}_r,{P_{1}}^r+{P_{2}}^r={P_{3}}^r+{P_{4}}^r\\
{P_{i}}^r=\gamma_i m_iV_i^r,r={1,2,3,4.}
$$ 
Here I have used tensor notation. Then the question is: how can I find $V_3,V_4$ in terms of $m_i,e,V_1,V_2$, where $e$ is the resititution coefficient? Or can we obtain any other meaningful relations?

Comment: I am not a specialist on this, but maybe if SR books don't contain your answer you need to look into General Relativity books. I would imagine that modelling collisions of stars cannot be done under perfect elastic or non-elastic constraints.

Comment: Also, don't expect to get away with a single coefficient (of restitution). I would expect it to become a full tensor, and probably even relative tensor once the real treatment begins.