# Coefficient of restitution in Special Relativity (duplicate)

Tags: special-relativity, collision

This is a duplicate of the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490946/) linked.

I have not been able to find any treatment of this concept. Is it even possible to incorporate such collisions in SR, and if so, how?